# undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'

Tags: c++, winsock, cmake

Что нужно добавить в CMakeList чтобы подключить Ws2_32.lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>На основании [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15124455/3240681) с enSO:</sup>

```
add_executable(MyExe main.cpp)
if(WIN32)
  target_link_libraries(MyExe ws2_32)
endif()
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто добавил `link_libraries(ws2_32 wsock32)`

Answer (score -1):

target_link_libraries и   ws2_32

Comment: Конкретную строку можно. Со скобками, кавычками и другими тонкостями.